# Dynamic Serialization for related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    """
    Country model
    """
    # With name and isoCode (charfield) 
    ...
class State(models.Model):
    """
    State model
    """
    # With name and isoCode (charfield) 
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
class City(models.Model):
    """
    City model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

And UserLocation referenced by:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="location")
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How do I build a serializer that creates UserLocation, as well as return the info in JSON?

I have tried

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="isoCode", queryset=Country.objects.all())
    state = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="isoCode", queryset=State.objects.filter(country__isoCode=country))
    city = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset=City.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ["user", "country", "state", "city"]
```

But it does not work, it gives the error
 `{"state":["Object with isoCode=BC does not exist."],...`

How does one create a dynamic linked serializer? Or how does one work around this?

Comment: Have you already prepopulated your db with these models (Country, State, City)? Did you try with `read_only=True`?

Comment: Remove the `country` field from the `City` model and make the `Location` model with the `city` field only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want following serializer

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="country.isocode")
    state = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="state.isocode")
    city = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="city.name")
    
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ["user", "country", "state", "city"]
```

However, it seems your model design is incorrect.
You don't need to have country, state foreign keys in Location model, since City model has state, State model has country.

Comment: This would work for display, but not for creation

Answer (score 0):

For future users. I found that

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''Used to serialize user location'''
    country = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="isoCode", queryset=Country.objects.all(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ["user", "country"]
        extra_kwargs = {"user": { "validators":[UniqueValidator(queryset=Location.objects.all(), message=_("User already has a location. Please update user location. Hint: use PUT request"))]}}


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if "country" in kwargs['context']['request'].data and len(Country.objects.get(isoCode=self.initial_data["country"]).state_set.all()) > 0:
            self.fields["state"] = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="isoCode", queryset=State.objects.filter(country__isoCode=self.initial_data["country"]), required=True)
            
            if "state" in kwargs['context']['request'].data and len(State.objects.get(isoCode=self.initial_data["state"], country__isoCode=self.initial_data["country"]).city_set.all()) > 0:
                self.fields["city"] = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", queryset=City.objects.filter(state__isoCode=self.initial_data["state"],country__isoCode=self.initial_data["country"]), required=True)
```

Seemed to work for my case